# getting a Matrix 4x4 error from transform.position, wondering how to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been poking around online and trying to figure out why this is happening, but I can't come to the conclusion myself. The line Vector3 place = allTiles[i].transform.position; results in an error states:

'Matrix4x4' does not contain a definition for 'position' and no accessible extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'Matrix4x4' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

was wondering if anyone may help me with this or point me in the right direction

```
    private void InitializeGraph()
{
    graph = new Graph();

    for (int i = 0; i < allTiles.Count; i++)
    {
        Vector3 place = allTiles[i].transform.position;
        graph.AddNode(place);
    }

    var allNodes = graph.Nodes;
    foreach (Node from in allNodes)
    {
        foreach (Node to in allNodes)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(from.worldPosition, to.worldPosition) < 1f && from != to)
            {
                graph.AddEdge(from, to);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that `allTiles[i].transform` is not returning a transform but rather a `Matrix4x4`? Then when you try to call position on it, it can't find it because it's not a transform?

Comment: To me, what you're saying makes sense. allTiles is pulling components from a gameobject, so I don't really get why it sees it as a Matrix4x4

Comment: I would check the type of `allTiles[i]` and check if the `allTiles[i].transform` is of a different type then you expect it to be. If `allTiles[i]` is a MonoBehaviour/Component, you could try to do `allTiles[i].gameObject.transform` and see if that gets the actual transform.

Comment: Thank you so much! I implemented the .gameObject and that worked. Thanks for the quick responses and help

Comment: Happy to help! I've added an answer with an explanation of what is happening feel free to accept it as the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be that `allTiles[i].transform` is not returning a `Transform` but rather a `Matrix4x4`. When calling `.position` on it, it cannot be found as `Matrix4x4` doesn't have a `position` field.

If allTiles[i] is aMonoBehaviour/Component you can use `allTiles[i].gameObject.transform` to get the gameobject and then the transform of the gameobject.

This is most likely happening because `allTiles[i]` has a field defined called `transform` that hides the original MonoBehaviour transform.

The following would be the expected behaviour of getting a transform when calling a .transform on a `MonoBehaviour`.

```
public class UsualTransform:MonoBehaviour
{

}
```

Calling the transform on a type of UsualTransform will result in the Transform

```
UsualTransform usualBehaviour = gameObject.AddComponent<UsualTransform>();
Transform transformOfTheMonoBehaviour = usualBehaviour.transform;
```

However if we add a field that hides the original field by adding a field with the same name as is defined in the `Monobehaviour` we get a different result.

```
public class HidingTransform:MonoBehaviour
{
    //this will hide the transform and return the string when calling it
    public string transform;
}
```

Calling the transform on a type of HidingTransform however will result in a different type as it is overriden by a different field. Resulting in a Matrix4x4 in your case and a string in this case

```
HidingTransform hiddenBehaviour = gameObject.AddComponent<HidingTransform>();
string stringOfTheMonoBehaviour = hiddenBehaviour.transform;
```